# Why am I getting this unknown option error

Tags: bash, sed

I am new to UNIX scripting and I am trying to use the sed command to replace text but I keep getting this error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 51: unknown option to `s'

Here is a snippet of the code that I have:

```
sed -e "/^#PBS -o ${rundir}/posttest/s#_CMODEL#${cmodel}#"  \
      -e "/^#PBS -e ${rundir}/posttest/s#_CMODEL#${cmodel}#"  \
     ${rundir}/run_post.shell >${rundir}/run_post.${cmodel}.sh
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Does `${rundir}` have `/` characters in it?

Comment: If you expect `/^#PBS -o ${rundir}/posttest/` to be a regex pattern which indicates which lines the  `s` command will apply to, then you need to escape the inner `/`. Otherwise, some explanation of what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: @Barmar yes ${rundir} does have / in it does that change anything

Comment: You need to escape all the slashes in the regular expression, both the explicit one before `posttest` and the ones that are in the variable.

Comment: @rici I am trying to replace the _CMODEL with what is stored in the variable cmodel. Right now that does not happen when the file name remains posttest_CMODEL

Comment: How would escape the slashes in the variable?

Comment: If you are running `bash` you may try `sed -e "/^#PBS -\(o\|e\) ${rundir//\//\\\/}\/postest/s#_CMODEL#${cmodel}#" ${rundir}/run_post.shell >${rundir}/run_post.${cmodel}.sh`.

Comment: Ooopss forgot to remove `-e` option in my previous comment.

Comment: Uhh, instead of having to escape the contents of your variable you can always just use regex delimiters that aren't slashes. You can use pretty much any non-special character as a delimiter. Try `:` or `!` or even `,`. eg: `s/foo/bar/` is the same as `s!foo!bar!` or `s,foo,bar,`

Comment: @alvits: good catch. But `-[eo]` is quite a bit easier on the eyes than `-\(o\|e\)`, and `\|` is a Gnu sed extension which may not be available in all seds.

Comment: @Sammitch - that's only useful for `s` command. Try it for `address` location and see how it goes. Compare `sed -n '/root/p' /etc/passwd` with `sed -n '!root!p' /etc/passwd` or `sed -n '|root|p' /etc/passwd` and share us your experience.

Comment: @rici - I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the regular expression you are using as an address is terminated by the first `/`, which might be in `${rundir}` or might be the `/` immediately following that; it is certainly not the `/` after `posttest`.

In general, interpolating variables into a regular expression is somewhat dangerous. If the variable's contents include regular expression metacharacters, then things are likely to fail in unexpected ways. If, as is the case here, the variable's value might include the regular expression terminator, then part of the variable's value will be interpreted as a command.

With that warning in mind, you have a couple of options. If you know that some character, say `:`, does not appear in `${rundir}`, then you can use the that character as a regular expression terminator. (Note the backslash, which is how you tell sed that what follows is a regular expression.)

```
sed -e "\:^#PBS -o ${rundir}/posttest:s#_CMODEL#${cmodel}#"  \
    -e "\:^#PBS -e ${rundir}/posttest:s#_CMODEL#${cmodel}#"  \
    "${rundir}/run_post.shell" >"${rundir}/run_post.${cmodel}.sh"
```

Alternatively, you could backslash-escape the literal `/` and use bash's pattern-substitution syntax to backslash-escape all the `/` in `$rundir`:

```
${rundir//\//\\/}
```

(As mentioned above, you really should escape *all* possible metacharacters, including backslashes themselves.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the slashes in the regular expression that's being used as the address. Otherwise, the first slash will end the regexp, and the next character will be taken as a `sed` command to operate on those selected lines. You need to do this for both the slashes in `$rundir` and the slash that you have between `${rundir}` and `posttest`.

For the variable, you can escape the slashes using bash's `${parameter/pattern/replacement}` syntax, described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

```
sed -e "/^#PBS -o ${rundir//\//\\/}\/posttest/s#_CMODEL#${cmodel}#"  \
      -e "/^#PBS -e ${rundir//\//\\/}\/s#_CMODEL#${cmodel}#"  \
     ${rundir}/run_post.shell >${rundir}/run_post.${cmodel}.sh
```